# Processing S4 object of data class .MultipleRasterData in RStudio

Tags: python, raster, r, netcdf, rstudio

I downloaded Era5 single level data using Python, where I tried to calculate daily_means from hourly data prior to downloading. I read the returned NetCDF-file into RStudio using
nc_file <- "path/download.nc"
raster_data <- raster::brick(nc_file)

This results in a LargeRasterBrick (with more than 5 million elements) of type S4. From here on I have no idea how to check the dataset, if it contains the information I was trying to get. This is my Python code I used to create and download:

```
import cdsapi
c = cdsapi.Client(url="https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/api/v2", key=f"{UID}:{API_KEY}")
request = {
...     'product_type': 'reanalysis',
...     'format': 'netcdf',
...     'variable': ['10m_u_component_of_wind', '10m_v_component_of_wind'],
...     'year': [str(year) for year in range(2010, 2021)],  # Range for the years 2010-2020
...     'month': [str(month).zfill(2) for month in range(1, 13)],  # All months
...     'day': [str(day).zfill(2) for day in range(1, 32)],  # All days of the month
...     'area': [58, -10, 52, 4],  # Nordsee bounding box [North, West, South, East]
...     'grid': [0.25, 0.25],  # Spatial resolution (0.25 degrees in both latitude and longitude)
...     'time': '00:00',  # Initial time of the forecast (start of the day)
... }
c.retrieve('reanalysis-era5-single-levels', request, 'download.nc')
```

So the dataset should contain u- and v-components of wind as daily means from 2010-2020. My goal is to perform a trend analysis for windspeed and direction. How do I handle an object like this in R?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use R, why not use the [`ecmwfr`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ecmwfr) package to query the CDS API? Then, use [`terra`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/terra/) or [`stars`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=stars) to conduct your statistical analysis on the raster data. Both packages let you read NetCDF files into your R session and provide you with advanced tooling for statistical analysis. You will have to do your own search for adequate methods for your research questions, but searching for `terra` or `sf` with your preferred search engine shoud quickly get you going.

Below, I show how you can query the CDS and use `terra` to read in the downloaded NetCDF file as a SpatRaster. Note, I only download the data for a single hour, so you'll have to adjust the query to your desired time frame.

```r
library(ecmwfr)
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.67

key <- "<your-api-key>"
user <- "<your-user-id>"

wf_set_key(user = user, key = key, service = "cds")

request <- list(
  product_type = "reanalysis",
  format = "netcdf",
  variable = c("10m_u_component_of_wind", "10m_v_component_of_wind"),
  year = "2010",
  month = "01",
  day = "01",
  time = "00:00",
  area = c(58, -10, 52, 4),
  dataset_short_name = "reanalysis-era5-single-levels",
  target = "download.nc"
)


outdir <- tempdir()
ncfile <- wf_request(
  user = user,
  request = request,
  transfer = TRUE,
  path = outdir,
  verbose = FALSE
)
#> - staging data transfer at url endpoint or request id:
#>   e19a84c7-4e8e-41fb-acd3-303b9e867aa7
#> - timeout set to 1.0 hours
#> - polling server for a data transfer\ polling server for a data transfer| polling server for a data transfer/ polling server for a data transfer- polling server for a data transfer\ polling server for a data transfer| polling server for a data transfer/ polling server for a data transfer- polling server for a data transfer\ polling server for a data transfer| polling server for a data transfer/ polling server for a data transfer- polling server for a data transfer\ polling server for a data transfer| polling server for a data transfer/ polling server for a data transfer- polling server for a data transfer\ polling server for a data transfer| polling server for a data transfer/ polling server for a data transfer- polling server for a data transfer\ polling server for a data transfer| polling server for a data transfer/ polling server for a data transfer- polling server for a data transfer
#> Downloading file
#>   |                                                                              |                                                                      |   0%  |                                                                              |======================================================================| 100%
#> - moved temporary file to -> /tmp/RtmpxLKDzd/download.nc
#> - Delete data from queue for url endpoint or request id:
#>   https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/api/v2/tasks/e19a84c7-4e8e-41fb-acd3-303b9e867aa7

r <- rast(ncfile)
plot(r)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>